# Can't find openvswitch-brcompat on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: software-installation

Like title says...and if I look into kernel modules I just find `openvswitch.ko`.
I am on ubuntu 13.10 and I installed,

```
openvswitch-controller
openvswitch-switch 
openvswitch-datapath-source 
openvswitch-datapath-dkms
```

when i try to install `openvswitch-brcompat` it just says it can't find any package named like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you following any installation guide?

Comment: http://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/08/17/installing-kvm-and-open-vswitch-on-ubuntu/

Comment: are you running 32 bit machine or 64 bit?

Comment: 32bit machine here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below  line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and then save it,

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main universe
```

Update the repositories,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the package,

```
sudo apt-get install openvswitch-brcompat
```